# Unexpected closure with Context import in Android

Tags: android, android-context

I am trying to import a context into this android file using the Context transfer. But if my message contains "aakash", then this code unexpectedly terminates giving the error as shown after the code.

What do I do ?

```
    public class messagebody extends BroadcastReceiver{

             Context mContext;
             public messagebody(Context context){
                   this.mContext = context;
                   Log.i(TAG, "yayyyy: " );
              }
             public messagebody(){

          }


            private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
            private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                 Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

                    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
                        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                        if (bundle != null) {
                            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                            }
                            if (messages.length > -1) {
                               // Toast.makeText(context, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody(), 7000).show();
                                if(messages[0].getMessageBody().contains("aakash"))
                                {
                                    /*AudioManager am = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                                    switch (am.getRingerMode()) {   
                                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:   
                                            //Log.i("MyApp","NORMAL mode");
                                            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                                            Toast toast2=Toast.makeText(mContext, "Vibrate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
                                            toast2.show();
                                            break;                
                                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:   
                                            //Log.i("MyApp","VIBRATE mode");
                                            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                                            Toast toast1=Toast.makeText(mContext, "Normal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
                                            toast1.show();
                                            break;   */
                                    Toast toast1=Toast.makeText(mContext, "Normal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
                                    toast1.show();
                                    } 

                                }
                                }
                            }
                        }

    }
```

The error is as follows :

```
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.messages.messagebody: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2236)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at com.example.messages.messagebody.onReceive(messagebody.java:68)
11-26 15:03:43.150: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2229)
```

With the mContext changed to context I get a null pointer exception with the new code. The code is

```
    package com.example.messages;
import com.example.messages.R;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class messagebody extends BroadcastReceiver{

             Context mContext;
             public messagebody(Context context){
                   this.mContext = context;
                   Log.i(TAG, "yayyyy: " );
              }
             public messagebody(){

          }


            private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
            private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                 Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

                    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
                        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                        if (bundle != null) {
                            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                            }
                            if (messages.length > -1) {
                               // Toast.makeText(context, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody(), 7000).show();
                                if(messages[0].getMessageBody().contains("aakash"))
                                {
                                    Toast toast3=Toast.makeText(context, "Normal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
                                    toast3.show();
                                    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                                    switch (am.getRingerMode()) {   
                                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:   
                                            //Log.i("MyApp","NORMAL mode");
                                            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                                            Toast toast2=Toast.makeText(context, "Vibrate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
                                            toast2.show();
                                            break;                
                                        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:   
                                            //Log.i("MyApp","VIBRATE mode");
                                            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                                            Toast toast1=Toast.makeText(context, "Normal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
                                            toast1.show();
                                            break;   

                                    } 

                                }
                                }
                            }
                        }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Your context variable is context, not mContext

Comment: Same error as old logcat? If not, post the new logcat output, too

Comment: At which line you are getting error now.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
Toast toast1=Toast.makeText(context, "Normal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
 toast1.show();
```

instead of

```
  Toast toast1=Toast.makeText(mContext, "Normal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
  toast1.show();
```

use current `BroadcastReceiver` `Context` to show  `Toast` from `BroadcastReceiver` instead of any old  Activity or Service Context

Comment: The problem might also be in the getSystemService. It was not working with the context of the current class.

Comment: @AakashAnuj : i'm not able to see any change in latest code as posted by you. you are still using mContext so plz replace mContext with context in all toast

Comment: and what about the getSystemService?

Comment: what is line number messagebody.java:68 in messagebody.java ?

Comment: getSystemService is f9 because  log clearing saying you have problem with Toast Messages

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver` Context

Comment: I changed the mCOntext to context, but now I am getting a null pointer exception. Now what is the problem?

Comment: also change `AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); `instead of `AudioManager am = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);`

Comment: Thanx @imran Working now :)

Comment: In that case, I dont think that there is any requirement of the Context import. Right?

Comment: @AakashAnuj : i already told you use BroadcastReceiver Context instead of other

Comment: yes,but if you want to use BroadcastReceiver Context in whole messagebody class means in other custom method apart from onReceive then you will need to Create a Class level Context and give onRecive context to it.as @Override
            `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {this.mContext = context; //your code }`